# How to start rails application running on certain ports on a machine re-boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn, rvm-capistrano

How to start rails application using unicorn on a machine re-boot in a EC2 instance. We use capistrano to deploy and start, but would like to know how to address this on a machine re-boot.